# Can I use asm() in C instead of asm?

Tags: c, operating-system, assemblies

I want to write a simple operating system for learning purposes.
Can I write an operating system using asm() in C instead of assembly language?

Example:

```
int main()
{
asm("mov ax,70C0h"
    "add ax,520"
    "jmp $");
}
```

Comment: You can write asm as part of a C program, but not as the *only* way to create an OS. There likely has to be some naked asm code at the "bottom" to load the very first program. Who is going to call `main()`, for example?

Comment: You _can_ but I think the issue is obvious. Note you also need an explicit `\n` in each string at the end: `"mov ax,70C0h\n"`. So, for any non-trivial sequence (e.g. 10+ lines) it's actually _more_ cumbersome to use an `asm` C directive than to write your own `.s` file. And, where you want to use assembly code is [usually] the bootstrap that has exact requirements for where code is placed (e.g. `org` directive). Again, while you _can_ do this, _nobody_ does this because it's more difficult to write, read, and understand with no upside benefit.

Answer (score 2):

You can't write an OS using inline Assembly, as the C compiler is going to compile and link the code on your existing OS. It can only be executed on your OS after that. I recommend writing your OS in Assembly and then compiling it using NASM (a common x86 compiler). I recommend [this tutorial](https://www.alanfoster.me/posts/writing-a-bootloader/) for creating your own bootloader. After that you can stick to 16-bit real mode or switch to [32-bit protected mode](https://wiki.osdev.org/Protected_Mode).